# Incorrect Query Result

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the following data:

```
    unit_codes
    kind    | code
-------------------------
    UNIT    | PS3b
    UNIT    | PS3B
    UNIT    | PS3C
```

If I run this select I get the correct result.

```
select * from unit_codes where kind = 'UNIT';
```

Result:

```
UNIT    PS3b
UNIT    PS3B 
UNIT    PS3C
```

If I filter on the code column I get no rows.

```
select * from unit_codes where code = 'PS3C';
```

No rows are retuned.

I suspect there is a non visible character on the code column for some rows. The problem started after some OS patches were installed.

We are running PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on sparc-sun-solaris2.10, compiled by cc: Sun C 5.9 SunOS_sparc 2007/05/03, 32-bit.

Comment: "I suspect there is a non visible character on the code column for some rows" - you almost nailed it. Better check the database to see if you have hidden chars. I have not used postgre yet but this is the same case when migrating to different databases using a script. Base on experience, the culprit was the \CR\LF pairs.

Comment: What is the **exact** data type definition of the code column?

Comment: Can you check if `where code like 'PS3C%'` returns anything? Or `where code like '%PS3C%'`

Comment: The datatype for the code column is VARCHAR(5). Both like 'PC3C%' and '%PC3C%' both return the correct result. trim(code) = 'PS3C' also works.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from invisible characters, the possibility of an OS patch changing the results of such an query exists through a change in locales.

An index involving text types is only valid if the underlying collation never changes. Postgres relies on the OS for comparing strings, through the libc, so **a change in an OS collation may have the effect of an index becoming unusable**, as if it was corrupted.

If there is an index on the column, you can test this hypothesis by issuing `SET enable_indexscan TO off;` before the offending query and see if it gives the same results. This check may also reveal an index corruption independantly of any problem with the collation.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, we found that running a vacuum on the table resolved the problem. I will try to restore a backup to test your hypothesis.